# Android overflow-y: auto scrolling problems

Tags: android, scroll, overflow

We are developing a android app and we have some probems with overflow-y: scroll. Because we have a sticky-footer bar we need this functionality for our content area.

When we enable overflow-y: scroll on our content div, the scrolling isn't smooth and very hicky. Sometimes there is also a lot of white-space at the bottom of the content element.

How can we solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing this also, I haven't come up with a solution that I'm happy with but we did work around it by just implementing a javascript scroll instead with using overflow: hidden and setting scrollTop based on user input, or using a plugin